# asp net c# code behind bind textbox to textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, bind, behind

Hello i have a calculations page and has many textboxes created dynamically. What i want to do is when the first textbox value changed, change the others code behind without using javascript or events. Is there any way to bind textBoxes like this.

Thnx

Ex.Code that i use

```
tb = new TextBox()
{
    ID = String.Format("tb_{0}_{1}_{2}_{3}", x, y, z, i),
    Width = 130,
    TextMode = TextBoxMode.Number,
    Text = ((TextBox)(Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl(String.Format("tb_{0}_{1}_{2}", x, y, z)))).Text.ToString()
};
```

There is link for sample view for textboxes
http://oi61.tinypic.com/2hd8f8p.jpg

Comment: why do you want to do this without javascript?

Comment: What you're asking for makes no sense.  You can only change other controls by **using** javascript and/or events.

Comment: processing each key press in a code behind to update the other text box would require an event as well as a post back for each key press. Clearly this is not desirable.

Comment: I know there is window controls binding for this, but want to know any binding for web controls

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you would have to set AutoPostBack to true on the textbox, and handle the OnTextChanged event.  When the user changes the text of the textbox and leaves the textbox, the page should perform a postback, allowing you to handle this event.  To my knowledge, this is the closest you can get without JavaScript.

If you don't want events either.. then... this is impossible..